# os.listdir() FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x

Такой код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
handle = open('config.conf')
data = handle.read()
os.listdir(data)
```

Содержимое `config.conf`:

```
C:\Users\Алекс\Desktop\DefendMySystem
```

Ошибка:

> ```
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] Системе не удается найти указанный путь: 
>    'C:\\Users\\РЎР°С€Р°\\Desktop\\DefendMySystem'
> ```

Как можно пофиксить это?

Comment: Что выдает `print(data)`, если вписать перед `os.listdir(data)`? Если такие же кракозябры, открывайте файл с кодировкой utf-8: `open('config.conf', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Сработало, спасибо.

Comment: @floydya: кодировка ввода/вывода (используемая print) может отличаться от кодировки, используемой для выбранного файла (и обе кодировки могут отличаться от кодировки исходного кода, указанной как utf-8 здесь). Более того, разные файлы могут использовать разные кодировки. Сам файл может не содержать информации о том какую кодировку следует использовать (некоторые варианты могут быть более вероятными, но гарантии нет)¶ Кратко: не во всех случаях utf-8 подходит для чтения файла.

Comment: txt = "РЎР°С€Р°"
print(txt)
txt_to_bytes = txt.encode("cp1251")
print(txt_to_bytes.decode()) -> Саша Вообще чтобы избежать проблем с виндовс дальше рекомендую имя пользователя прописать латиницей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убедитесь, что файл config.conf имеет кодировку именно utf-8 и укажите кодировку при открытии файла - `handle = open('config.conf', encoding='utf-8')`.